# Reformat dataframe by moving begin time and end time based on group to begin and end time in new dataframe without looping

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, dplyr

I have a working set of code using a for loop below to process a dataframe but need to optimize it without a for loop if possible.  I have searched for a while to find something like this but must not know the proper search terms. Thanks for any help.

The dataframe example (longer version at the bottom) has a datetime column and a bottle column. The bottle column begins at some number (1 below) and will repeat as samples are added and switch to 2 and so on till bottle 7 (in this case) and then **RESTARTS** at 1 and goes to 14 (in this case) and over and over. (Note that there are more than 2 times per bottle in the real file)

```
datetime        bottle
6/9/2016 0:00   1
6/9/2016 0:15   1
6/9/2016 0:30   1
6/9/2016 0:45   1
6/9/2016 1:00   2
6/9/2016 1:15   2
6/9/2016 1:30   2
6/9/2016 1:45   3
6/9/2016 2:00   3
6/9/2016 2:15   4
6/9/2016 2:30   4
6/9/2016 2:45   5
6/9/2016 3:00   5
6/9/2016 3:15   6
6/9/2016 3:30   6
6/9/2016 3:45   7
6/9/2016 4:00   7
6/9/2016 4:15   7
6/9/2016 4:30   1
6/9/2016 4:45   1
6/9/2016 5:00   1
6/9/2016 5:15   2
6/9/2016 5:30   2
6/9/2016 5:45   2
6/9/2016 6:00   3
6/9/2016 6:15   3
6/9/2016 6:30   3
```

I need to create a new dataframe with bottle begin and end times. Note that each sequence of bottles is repeated.

```
  bottle begin         end
    1   6/9/2016 0:00   6/9/2016 0:45
    2   6/9/2016 1:00   6/9/2016 1:30
    3   6/9/2016 1:45   6/9/2016 2:00
    4   6/9/2016 2:15   6/9/2016 2:30
    5   6/9/2016 2:45   6/9/2016 3:00
    6   6/9/2016 3:15   6/9/2016 3:30
    7   6/9/2016 3:45   6/9/2016 4:15
    1   6/9/2016 4:30   6/9/2016 5:00
    2   6/9/2016 5:15   6/9/2016 5:45
    3   6/9/2016 6:00   6/9/2016 6:30
```

What I have done so far is the annotated code below. This works well but takes a long time on the full dataframe.

```
#create id number for each bottle using data.table
setDT(t2s_bottle_timing.df)[, id := .GRP, by = t2s_bottle]

#declare/set variables
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 1
x3 <- 1
i <- 1
N <- length(t2s_bottle_timing.df$t2s_bottle)

#renumber id column to have unique id for each bottle run
for (i in 2:(N-1)) {
  x1 <- t2s_bottle_timing.df[(i) , 2] #load bottle numbers
  x2 <- t2s_bottle_timing.df[(i+1) , 2] #load bottle numbers
  if (x2 == x1)  {   t2s_bottle_timing.df[(i),3] <- x3 } #set id number
  if (x2 != x1)  {   x3 <- x3 +1} #increment id number
  t2s_bottle_timing.df[(i+1),3] <- x3 #load new id number into table
}

# get rid of unused stuff
rm(x1, x2, i, N, x3)

# summerise the raw dataframe to produce the bottle, begin, end dataframe
t2s_timing_output.df <- t2s_bottle_timing.df %>% group_by( id ,t2s_bottle ) 
  %>%  #group_by(id,bottle)
  summarize(
    begin = min(datetime),
    end = max(datetime) )
```

So this works but I am eager to learn an alternative way and more efficient way to do this.

```
t2s_bottle_timing.df <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1465514100, 1465515000, 
1465515900, 1465516800, 1465517700, 1465518600, 1465519500, 1465520400, 
1465521300, 1465522200, 1465523100, 1465524000, 1465524900, 1465525800, 
1465526700, 1465527600, 1465528500, 1465529400, 1465530300, 1465531200, 
1465532100, 1465533000, 1465533900, 1465534800, 1465535700, 1465536600, 
1465537500, 1465538400, 1465539300, 1465540200, 1465541100, 1465542000, 
1465542900, 1465543800, 1465544700, 1465545600, 1465546500, 1465547400, 
1465548300, 1465549200, 1465550100, 1465551000, 1465551900, 1465552800, 
1465553700, 1465554600, 1465555500, 1465556400, 1465557300, 1465558200, 
1465559100, 1465560000, 1465560900, 1465561800, 1465562700, 1465563600, 
1465564500, 1465565400, 1465566300, 1465567200, 1465568100, 1465569000, 
1465569900, 1465570800, 1465571700, 1465572600, 1465573500, 1465574400, 
1465575300, 1465576200, 1465577100, 1465578000, 1465578900, 1465579800, 
1465580700, 1465581600, 1465582500, 1465583400, 1465584300, 1465585200, 
1465586100, 1465587000, 1465587900, 1465588800, 1465589700, 1465590600, 
1465591500), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    t2s_bottle = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L)), .Names = c("datetime", "t2s_bottle"), row.names = c(NA, 
-87L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(datetime = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), t2s_bottle = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("datetime", "t2s_bottle")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what begin and end times correspond to. How can begin time be after end time (for ex. in row 2) ?

Comment: sorry when I was trying to make the example it is supposed to increment by 15 minutes form the beginning and in excel (sorry) I messed this up and will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example confuses me a little bit, but if what you want is to create an index maybe `cumsum` with a logical could help:

```
t2s_bottle_timing.df %>% 
mutate(index = cumsum(t2s_bottle != dplyr::lag(t2s_bottle, default = 0))) %>% 
group_by(index, t2s_bottle) %>% 
summarise(begin = min(datetime), end = max(datetime))

   index t2s_bottle               begin                 end
   <int>      <int>              <dttm>              <dttm>
1      1          1 2016-06-09 23:15:00 2016-06-10 00:15:00
2      2          2 2016-06-10 00:30:00 2016-06-10 02:15:00
3      3          3 2016-06-10 02:30:00 2016-06-10 04:30:00
4      4          4 2016-06-10 04:45:00 2016-06-10 06:00:00
5      5          5 2016-06-10 06:15:00 2016-06-10 07:45:00
6      6          6 2016-06-10 08:00:00 2016-06-10 09:00:00
7      7          7 2016-06-10 09:15:00 2016-06-10 10:15:00
8      8          1 2016-06-10 10:30:00 2016-06-10 11:15:00
9      9          2 2016-06-10 11:30:00 2016-06-10 13:00:00
10    10          3 2016-06-10 13:15:00 2016-06-10 13:30:00
11    11          4 2016-06-10 13:45:00 2016-06-10 15:00:00
12    12          5 2016-06-10 15:15:00 2016-06-10 15:45:00
13    13          6 2016-06-10 16:00:00 2016-06-10 17:15:00
14    14          7 2016-06-10 17:30:00 2016-06-10 18:45:00
15    15          8 2016-06-10 19:00:00 2016-06-10 20:45:00
```

Comment: Sometimes I think my skill in learning R and doing science is making things as complicated as I possibly can. This is exactly what I needed and an elegant and super fast solution to my problem - thank you so much.